# Unknown email address sending email from my host

Tags: centos, centos6, exim

I have a centOS 6 server, with DirectAdmin as the management panel and Exim as the mail server.
In usage directory files (/etc/virtual/usage/) I can see that some emails have been sent from users that don't exist in my mail users. The IP address 114.222.66.5 does not belong to the server. Here's the file content about sending emails:

```
716=type=email&email=beverlylau@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFCt-0000sT-OQ&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229565&message_size=716&local_part=janis.shampay&domain=reed.edu&path=/
677=type=email&email=andyfield@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFCw-0000sT-EC&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229566&message_size=677&local_part=hal&domain=miamihal.com&path=/
693=type=email&email=candyplk@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFCx-0000sT-CX&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229567&message_size=693&local_part=lohriner&domain=gmail.com&path=/
728=type=email&email=anwilknson@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFCy-0000sT-AD&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229569&message_size=728&local_part=donna.triboletti&domain=gmail.com&path=/
726=type=email&email=ccrosslnd@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFCz-0000sT-LF&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229570&message_size=726&local_part=jlljdy&domain=comcast.net&path=/
706=type=email&email=ccolbystreeter@domain.com&method=outgoing&id=1jYFD0-0000sT-I0&authenticated_id=realuser@domain.com&sender_host_address=114.222.66.5&log_time=1589229571&message_size=706&local_part=vocals1&domain=live.com&path=/
12840=type=email&email=alireza@domain.com&method=incoming&log_time=1589233327&id=1jYGBb-0002mm-Ai&path=/
15734=type=email&email=info@domain.ir&method=incoming&log_time=1589254173&id=1jYLbl-0003Ed-Jw&path=/
```

[image: direct admin]

Can anybody tell me what's going on and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the password of `realuser@domain.com` got leaked. Someone simply logged in to the server, and sent an email. The headers of the email are plain text, so the `Sender` column (which I'm assuming comes from the `From:` header) is arbitrary and thus, unreliable. The `Authentication` column contains the authenticated user, so those users need their password changed.

Comment: Thank you. This was the first thing I thought about. I changed the `realuser` password and now I have to wait and see if the problem resolves or not.

Comment: It seems that the problem was exactly what you said. Thanks.